# How to update/delete an embedded object

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah, salat

Given following domain model:

```
case class Benefits(id: Int, benefitPlan: String, comment : String)

case class Employee(empNum : Int, benefits : List[Benefit])
```

I've been using Salat to help derialize/deserialize these objects. However, I'm a little confused as to how to delete/update a specific object from the benefits List in employee object given that I know the benefit.id of the object that is to be deleted/updated?

I do not want to iterate the full benefits list to be able to update a single object since this list may hold large number of objects at runtime. Is there a better way than getting the emp object, iterating the list until desired object is found, update it and then save the emp object back?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I would say your `benefits` should be an `Map[Int, Benefits]`.

If you use `Map`, your update/delete will be O(1) instead of linear time.

`List` is not a good choice if you need randomly access and update an element in it.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my data structure to not require updates to List. I now only do add.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into this [article](http://bhameyie.com/2014/01/06/quick-tutorial-on-casbah-scalas-mongodb-driver) about Casbah and Salat (assuming you're using salat for MongoDB)

```
def removeBenefit(empNum : Int, benefitId: Int)= {
  val updateQuery = $pull("benefits " -> MongoDBObject("id" -> benefitId))
  val query = MongoDBObject("empNum " -> empNum )
  modify(query, updateQuery) // your findAndModify operation goes here
}
```